# Is there a difference in cytoplasmic pH between prokaryotes and eukaryotes?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, literature

The cytosolic pH in human cells is [around 7.4, but fluctuates as the cell is replicating](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2114443/). Prokaryotes and eukaryotes are vastly different in many ways. One thing they share is cytoplasm. Is there any general difference in the pH between these two cytosolic spaces? Any pointers to a previous investigation into this would be hugely appreciated. Ideally I'm after a quantified numerical comparison from a peer reviewed reference, but given the obscurity of the question that might be a tall order!

Googling was to no avail. It's swamped with pH survival data.

Answer (score 4):

In the article "pH of the Cytoplasm and Periplasm of Escherichia coli: Rapid Measurement by Green Fluorescent Protein Fluorimetry", by Jessica C. Wilks and Joan L. Slonczewski, the pH of E.coli cytoplasm was mentioned as 7.2 - 7.8. I just took E.coli's pH range as a common example of prokaryotes.

Reference link: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1951819/